# Looking for sysconf_addword explanation

Tags: linux, unix, apache-http-server

What is `sysconf_addword`?
Couldn't find a documentation about this. Is it apache specific?

Answer (score 0):

It's [this](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=sysconf_addword&package=apache2&project=Apache&rev=e58e0fbb59ac10f5bd5ab1da0700c742) - looks like a script to add or remove words to specified files.

There looks to be some sparse documentation inside that source which might help, but it's a bit thin.