# Can not understand this script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, script, sed

Can someone help me understand this script? It is from sysconf_add and I am new to scripting.
I need to do something similar.

```
function add_word() {  
    local word=$1  
    local word_quoted=$2  
    if ! word_present; then  
        $debug && cp $file $tmpf  
        sed -i -e "${lineno} {   
            s/^[[:space:]]*\($var=\".*\)\(\".*\)/\1 $word_quoted\2/;   
            s/=\" /=\"/   
            }" $file  
        $debug && diff -u $tmpf $file  
    else  
        echo \"$word\" already present  
    fi  
    # some balancing for vim"s syntax highlighting  
}
```

Comment: Maybe ask a more specific question? Which line you do not understand ? Also, you should give complete references (What is sysconf_add? What operating system? What shell does it uses?).

Comment: @vladmihaisima:I am interested in `sed`.I don't really know what is `sysconf_add`.http://superuser.com/questions/490956/looking-for-sysconf-addword-explanation. I think it is for apache

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a good resource for `sed`

For your example above:

- The `-i` flag means 'edit in-place' (GNU sed only), this is editing `$file` in-place
- The `-e` flag chains together multiple commands.
- The first command in your example looks to be replacing instances of `$var="<stuff>"` with the second argument passed to the script.
- The second command removes trailing space following the sequence `="` (e.g. `foo=" bar "` would become `foo="bar "`)